# In Angular, how do I inject a service into a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I make `app.js` like so:

```
var app = angular.module('game', ['ngRoute']);
```

I make `doorService.js` like this:

```
angular.module('game', [])
  .service('doorService', function() {
    this.drawDoors = function drawDoors() { 
      ....
    }
  })
```

And, lastly, my controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('game', [])
  .controller('canvasCtrl', function($scope, doorService) {
    ....
  })
```

---

**Errors**

[Error:$injector:modulerr Module Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=doorService&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DdoorService%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:6:423%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:24:186%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:23:252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20P.bootstrap%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:23:495)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:37:427%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:331)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:37:444%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.0-beta.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:331)

[Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=doorServiceProvider%20%3C-%20doorService%20%3C-%20canvasCtrl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your completed code should look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('game', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('game')
   .service('doorService', function() {
     this.drawDoors = function drawDoors() { 
     ....
   }
})


angular.module('game')
  .controller('canvasCtrl', function($scope, doorService) {
....
 })
```

Also, because you're creating the global variable app, all of the subsequent calls to angular.module('game') could be replaced with app.

Comment: even if the controller, service, and main module are in different files?

Comment: Yes, as long as the js file that creates the app variable is loaded before any of the others that reference it that works fine. That's a dependency for the modules either way actually though.

Comment: @PeterWard different files won't matter. Usually have module declaration load in first one ...after angular.js of course

Comment: I'm still getting some of the same errors. Would you mind checking my source code? There isn't much, I swear: [https://github.com/peter-atlanta/game](https://github.com/peter-atlanta/game)

Comment: The first thing I saw was that you're using the angular 1.5 beta. I'd recommend using 1.4.6 at least to get started. No sense in running into beta related issues on this.

Comment: @PeterWard missing the main module dependencies `ngRoute, ngAnimate` etc that you have as scripts in index

Comment: I was still checking out your code, but I see you accepted the answer. I'm confused. Are you good?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are redeclaring the same module repeatedly.

The getter for a module doesn't have the dependency argument

```
// declare once
angular.module('game', [/* dependencies*/])

// use as getter for components
angular.module('game').controller(...
```

Also optionally add injection dependencies array for controller if you plan to minify your code

Answer (score 1):

You must inject the dependencies into .module() first:

```
 angular.module('game')
    .controller('canvasCtrl', ['scope','doorService',function($scope, doorService) {
   ....
   })]
```

Comment: syntax is all wrong...scope and service don't get injected in module